# Swift, constraint, UILabel, anchor right

Tags: ios, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

Desired...

[image]

For some reason the following doesn't work:

```
extension UIView {
    func addWordOnRight() {
        let l = UILabel()

        //l.frame = self.bounds ..?

        l.textAlignment = .right
        l.text = "blah"

        self.addSubview(l)

        let m = self.layoutMarginsGuide
        l.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: m.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        l.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: m.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And if you l.frame = self.bounds, it mysteriously anchors to the left, not right.

Comment: Aren't you getting autolayout warnings with that code? The frame and constraints conflict. By adding `l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` (not setting the frame) I get your desired layout.

Comment: facepalm!  ah, you're brilliant @JamesP.  why not put that in as an answer, it will help others and you deserve the kudos/points!  :)

Comment: Haha, I wasn't sure it would be that simple.

Comment: "SIMPLE FOR YOU"  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the label has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `true`, so the view automatically adds constraints. When you add your own constraints these conflict with those already added. (You should be seeing lots of warnings in your console.)

If you want to use autolayout set `l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Your constraints should now work correctly.

In case you also want to set the width and height of the label, set those using constraints as well (leave the frame alone).

Comment: What a great answer.